# Can't get less.js to work

Tags: css, less

I can't get less.js to work and I have no idea why. Heres the HTML i tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet/less"  href="main.less" />

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <!-- <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.18.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="less-1.0.18.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Lorum ipsum
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And heres main.less:

```
p {
    color: blue;
}
```

The less-1.0.18.min.js file is downloaded from http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.18.min.js. All files is in the same folder. I have no idea why this isn't working...

Tested in Chrome 12.0.742.100

**Edit**

Tried the lates less.js file (less-1.1.3.min.js). That one did also not work.

**Okay now...**

This works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="main.less" />
```

But only as normal css, no less specific markup.

This doesn't work at all:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" href="main.less" />
```

Also, this isn't working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="main.less" />
```

What the hell? How do I get less to work?

**Found the error**

> P.S.S. Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known Chrome issue.

[Soruce](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/)

Comment: Good Question. i have same doubt!!!. but still i'm searching the solution.

Comment: @knarf: Your question solved my problem,  previously I was not using type="text/less" in link tag, due to which my less file was not working in firefox. but now its working. thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> *P.S.S. Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using
>   Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known
>   Chrome issue.*

But what we could do is setting up a local testing environment using wamp (pc) or mamap (mac). It will work alright then.

Comment: It didn't work for me with a "file:///" url, in either Opera Version
11.60 Build 1185 or I.E. 8.6001. When I used Firefox 3.6.17 & it worked just fine.

Comment: What's the point of this library if it's not supported by majority of browsers?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the command-line switch **-allow-file-access-from-files** when starting chrome - it will permit less.js to access local less files.

Comment: the simple and ideal method :)

Answer (score 3):

Even though this was posted a while ago I thought I would add a little something for other people stuck on this.

If you use a windows machine, you might want to give WinLess a try. Its a pre-compiler for windows. Seems straight forward to use. Good luck. 
http://winless.org/

Answer (score -3):

Need to add

> type="text/css"

to your css link.

Comment: @petah Guess again. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-you-need-to-check-out-less-js/

http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/

Comment: CORRECT: `<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="main.less" />` - I almost want to upvote this wrong answer because it is the one that made me check my code and see that I was missing `rel="stylesheet/less"`