# Unable to get Media queries working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modernizr

**UPDATE**  I've deployed a live version on my FTP [Link here](http://designobvio.us/DoV3/)!  Hopefully this will influence an answer or at least a leading comment? :(

[Modernizr 2.5+](http://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-25/) has taken away native support of respond.js.

**Problem:** When Loading yesnope.js from Modernizr 2.5+ how can I to run Respond.js for IE6~8 media-query compatibility?

**Potential answers:**

- The yesnope paths are incorrectly referenced.
- Missed a step in installation.
- hierarchy of scripts are conflicting
- ????

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/modernizr.full.min.js"></script>     
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/ggs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 1px)'),//true if media queries  supported
            nope: 'library/js/libs/respond.min.js'
            });
        </script>


    </body>
```

**File structure**
[image]

**additionally**
i've removed the [top portion](http://vvcap.net/db/jHwbDNBuDBXHAeNR6Jv5.png) of Modernizr because it insisted to (neither versions work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINALLY SOLVED IT!**
 Uncompiled LESS files are not recognized respond.js.  So use Simpless and you'll get respond.js to work in IE.

[Heres a similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372211/cant-get-less-js-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to share your directory structure, but does that address the issue?

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 1px)'),//true if media queries supported
    nope: 'library/js/libs/respond.min.js'
});
```

EDIT:
Try this, I tried to make the path more like the ones you were already using.

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 1px)'),//true if media queries supported
    nope: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/respond.min.js'
});
```

Comment: I put file structure because soemtimes the pathing can be not normal(css3pie).  Sometimes you need another / like '/library'.  Unfortunatly, this still isnt working.  Installation of this doesnt require any more then just copying and pasting the scripts right?

Comment: Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: I'd try re-getting a fresh copy of Modernizr (the full version or a custom one including both load and media queries).  Or maybe change my nope path to `'<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/respond.min.js'`.

Comment: What specific "no result" or failure are you getting.  Have you confirmed that Modernizr is loading and/or functional in any capacity?

Comment: yeah it adds the classes to the body as normal.

Comment: Next set of suggestions (if you still need any @MatthewHarwood): verify that the `load` function works in your copy of Modernizr by having it load a JS file you're currently (and successfully) loading somewhere else, verify my test condition by logging to the console something on completion of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Except Modernize should work standalone and out-of-the-box.

The idea is that you put it within your header tags in order to prevent a so called "flash of unstyled content".

In additition, Modernizr offers a lot of possibilities create a custom download:

http://modernizr.com/download/

On this page you have the possibility to explicitely include YepNope and MediaQuery stuff.

Comment: It looks like my question has confused you.  Modernizr has a custom feature called yesnope.js.  I'm unable to get yesnope to trigger a respond.js.

Comment: ahh looks like you edited your last comment.  Yes I understand this explicit inclusion; however, thats not the problem the problem is getting this to accually all work with IE media queries.