# LESS stylesheet not registering

Tags: hyperlink, grid, less

Is there a trick to LESS? I can't get any of it to function in-browser. Maybe I'm declaring the stylesheet in the browser wrong? It's literally just not showing up *at all*. I've included the min and the LESS files in the same folder, just to make sure that it's not a directory issue. Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <title>Jessica Colding</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" href="style.less"/>
    <script src="less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang="en">


        <div id="container"> Hello</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Would it work in xampp? without having to use simplLESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this directly from a file, you should change the URL for your script to include `http:` (protocol-less won't work for local files).

This makes sense, if you think about it, because you're not accessing your file via http, and the protocol-less reference tells the browser to use the same protocol as you did for the page.

EDIT: A good troubleshooting approach is to display the Error Console.  It can often shed light on problems such as this one.

Comment: I've checked the error console. I suppose maybe I'm too much of a noob to know what you mean by including HTTP protocols in my script? Where is it to be included? :D

Comment: Like this: `<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>`

Comment: So there's nothing in the error console after you reload the page?

Comment: Depending on your browser, there may be some filters that control what messages are visible.  Make sure that you aren't filtering out any messages.

Comment: I've been screwing around with a few things (I tried using a pre-compiler, and referencing the compiled, min'ed css file), and after declaring the LESS stylesheet, I'm getting this:

Comment: Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 less-1.3.3.min.js:8

Comment: So, I should reference an HTTP less-min.js file to circumvent this, correct?

Comment: Alright. The HTTP solution worked (I just uploaded the folder to a remote server.) It is not working locally, no matter how I reference the .less/min.js files.

Comment: How does someone developing in LESS usually work with LESS files? Do they work remotely from the server? Is there a browser fix? I've tried SimpLESS.... It has done absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: If you placed the files on a remote server, then adding `http` wasn't needed.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I tried to use HTTP addresses, and hosted the LESS/JS files remotely. That did not improve the situation. I don't know what else to do, other than to develop on a remote server.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions I provided up towards the top?

Answer (score 0):

[Can't get less.js to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372211/cant-get-less-js-to-work)

I've found this solution. I'm going to try testing it in a webserver, to see if it works. But, having tested it in several browsers, this is either a bug that is not only limited to Chrome, or there is a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

When running under IE9, `less` doesn't seem to work properly.  I tried a sample very similar to yours, and in the console window, I get an error:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
```

The error occurs on the xhr request:

```
xhr.open('GET', url, async);
```

I don't have any problems running this in Firefox, so if you're using IE, I would suggest trying a different browser.  There is presumably a security setting that can be changed to allow this (but I wasn't able to find it).